# Elastic Search multilingual field

Tags: elasticsearch, multilingual

I have read through few articles and advices, but unfortunately I haven't found working solution for me.

The problem is I have a field in index that can have content in any possible language and I don't know in which language it is. I need to search and sort on it. It is not localisation, just values in different languages.

The first language (excluding few European) I have tried it on was Japanese. For the beginning I set for this field only one analyzer and tried to search only for Japanese words/phrases. I took example from [here](http://gibrown.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/). Here is what I used for this:

```
'analysis': {
    "filter": {
    ...
        "ja_pos_filter": {
            "type": "kuromoji_part_of_speech",
            "stoptags": [
                "\\u52a9\\u8a5e-\\u683c\\u52a9\\u8a5e-\\u4e00\\u822c",
                "\\u52a9\\u8a5e-\\u7d42\\u52a9\\u8a5e"]
        },
    ...
    },
    "analyzer": {
    ...
        "ja_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": ["kuromoji_baseform", "ja_pos_filter", "icu_normalizer", "icu_folding", "cjk_width"],
            "tokenizer": "kuromoji_tokenizer"
        },
    ...
    },
    "tokenizer": {
        "kuromoji": {
            "type": "kuromoji_tokenizer",
            "mode": "search"
        }
    }
}
```

Mapper:

```
'name': {
    'type': 'string',
    'index': 'analyzed',
    'analyzer': 'ja_analyzer',
}
```

And here are few tries to get result from it:

```
{
    'filter': {
        'query': {
            'bool': {
                'must': [
                    {
                        # 'wildcard': {'name': u'*ネバーランド福島*'}
                        # 'match': {'name": u'ネバーランド福島'
                        # },
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ['name'],
                            "query": u'ネバーランド福島',
                            "default_operator": 'AND'
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'boost': 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

None of them works.

If I just take a standard analyser and query in with query_string or brake phrase myself (breaking on whitespace, what i don't have here) and use wildcard *<>* for this it will find me nothing again. Analyser says that ネバーランド and 福島 are separate words/parts:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=ja_analyzer&pretty' -d 'ネバーランド福島'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "ネハラント",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 6,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "福島",
    "start_offset" : 6,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

And in case of standard analyser I'll get result if I'll look for ネバーランド I'll get what I want. But if I use customised analyser and try the same or just one symbol I'm still getting nothing.

The behaviour I'm looking for is: breaking query string on words/parts, all words/parts should be present in resulting name field.

Thank you in advance